# Ckeditor inline editor stays on screen when scrolling a "scrollable" div

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, ckeditor

I have a **"scrollable"** div. Inside this div i have some text and another div with contenteditable=true.

The HTML source looks like this

```
<div id='scrollable' style="overflow:scroll;height:500px;width:90%;position:absolute">
some text
   <div id='editable' style="color:red" contenteditable=true>editable div</div>
some text
</div>
```

An inline ckeditor editor for the "editable" div should appear on page load. This is done by focusing the div.

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#editable").focus();
});
```

The problem is that when i scroll the "scrollable" div the inline editor stays on screen. I want it to stay "out of screen" when i scroll. I mean, i want it to behave like a regular element inside a scrollable div.

I prepared a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pteryvk3/1/) but for testing i recommend to view the result page [separately](https://fiddle.jshell.net/pteryvk3/1/show/). Tested in FF and Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
  $("#editable").focus();
     setInterval(function(){$("#cke_editable").css("top",($("#editable").offset().top - $("#cke_editable").height())+"px")})
});
```

See it work [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ibad_gore/pteryvk3/3/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it work only in Chrome and doesn't work in FF.

Comment: I added a time argument for setInterval (10) and now it works in FF. I will perform some tests and if it will work for me, i will set your answer as accepted.

Comment: Thats nice... I just gave you an example... You will have to do some more additions if you are working with more than one editor.